# Why recursive memory deallocation so slow?

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, heap-memory

I've made a Octree to match 3 dimensional points fast. And it is fast! However, deleting the octree takes 100 folds more time than building it. I don't understand why this is happening. This is my class:

```
#pragma once
#include "LeakCheck.h"
#include "vec3.h"

namespace Geometry 
{

static const float tolerance = 1.0e-30f;

class VertexOctree
{
private:
    float halfSize;
    vec3 center;
    VertexOctree *subTrees;
    int vertexIndex;
    void CreateSubTree()
    {
        subTrees = news VertexOctree[8];
        subTrees[0] = VertexOctree(center+(vec3(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f)*halfSize),halfSize*0.5f);
        subTrees[1] = VertexOctree(center+(vec3(+1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f)*halfSize),halfSize*0.5f);
        subTrees[2] = VertexOctree(center+(vec3(-1.0f,+1.0f,-1.0f)*halfSize),halfSize*0.5f);
        subTrees[3] = VertexOctree(center+(vec3(+1.0f,+1.0f,-1.0f)*halfSize),halfSize*0.5f);
        subTrees[4] = VertexOctree(center+(vec3(-1.0f,-1.0f,+1.0f)*halfSize),halfSize*0.5f);
        subTrees[5] = VertexOctree(center+(vec3(+1.0f,-1.0f,+1.0f)*halfSize),halfSize*0.5f);
        subTrees[6] = VertexOctree(center+(vec3(-1.0f,+1.0f,+1.0f)*halfSize),halfSize*0.5f);
        subTrees[7] = VertexOctree(center+(vec3(+1.0f,+1.0f,+1.0f)*halfSize),halfSize*0.5f);
    }
public:
    int AddVertex(std::vector<vec3> &VertexList, const vec3& Point)
    {
        if (vertexIndex == -1) {
            vertexIndex = VertexList.size();
            VertexList.push_back(Point);
            return vertexIndex;
        }
        if ((VertexList[vertexIndex]-Point).lengthSq() < tolerance) {
            return vertexIndex;
        }
        if (subTrees == NULL)
            CreateSubTree();

        return subTrees[(Point.x>center.x)+(2*(Point.y>center.y))+(4*(Point.z>center.z))].AddVertex(VertexList, Point);
    }
    VertexOctree()
    {
        subTrees = NULL;
        vertexIndex = -1;
    }
    VertexOctree(vec3 Center, float HalfSize)
    {
        subTrees = NULL;
        center = Center;
        halfSize = HalfSize;
        vertexIndex = -1;
    }
    ~VertexOctree()
    {
        if (subTrees)
            delete[] subTrees;
    }
};

};
```

When deleting a VertexOctree it takes a LONG time. Much longer than creating the trees which also has to do floating point operations to compare points and allocate the memory. Why is it so slow to delete it? I use Visual Studio 2012 and compile in release mode.

Comment: Is this in release or debug build? A debug build would be slow because it fills all the de-allocated memory before it's released to be reused (to detect if you are re-using it).

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 and compile in release mode. I meant release build.

Comment: You don't need to test `subTrees.` The `delete` operator already does that. There's no advantage to doing it twice.

Comment: I've once had a program take 4 hours to run destructors. `delete` can be really slow if the order of deallocation has no relation at all with the order of alloction, and you have literally tens of millions of objects. Locality of reference definitely matters.

Comment: I've been programming c++ for over ten years and never knew you could delete NULL pointers. That's 4000 if sentences wasted! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you press F5 to run your program, it uses a special, slower debug heap, even in release mode. If you press ctrl+F5, it uses the regular heap, even in debug mode. Try that and if it speeds it up, then in your project's debugging properties, in the environment box put _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1 to always use the fast heap.

Comment: That did it! Thanks alot. I did not know about that. How does this affect debugging? I didn't think it was possible to do any debugging in release build anyway.

Comment: You're welcome! I think that the debug heap does extra checks that you did not overwrite buffers or write to deleted memory.

Comment: You can run release mode with debugging on but it's harder as the code could have been changed due to optimizations.

Comment: To make that comment complete, don't test performance on debug build OR in debug environments. Quonox' comment is the classical comment, focusing on the first kind  of problem only, while this is a problem of the second kind.

Comment: In my defense, I was testing performance on release build. I didn't know that still was debugging. It's kind of misleading...